# OpenSCAD Variable not accumulating

Tags: openscad

I am fairly new to OpenSCAD and I've run into an issue that I don't understand. In the following snippet, the variable "ofs" is not accumulating from the previous value of the 'for' iteration.

```
slots = [5, 7, 11, 17];

ofs = 0;
for (i = slots) {
    ofs = ofs + i;
    echo (ofs);
    translate([ofs,0,0])
    cube([1, 50, 30]);
}
```

What I expect to see from `echo (ofs)` are the values:

- 5   (0 + 5)
- 12  (5 + 7)
- 23  (12 + 11)
- 30  (23 + 17)

What I'm actually seeing is just the value from the slots array:

- 5
- 7
- 12
- 23

Can someone tell me how I can the the value of ofs to accumulate through the iterations of the loop?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual strategy is to calculate the values first before going into the geometry generation, e.g.:

```
slots = [5, 7, 11, 17];
ofs = [ for (o = 0, i = 0;i < len(slots);o = o + slots[i],i = i + 1) o + slots[i]];
echo(slots = slots, ofs = ofs);
for (o = ofs) translate([o,0,0]) cube([1, 50, 30]);
```

Comment: People on StackOverflow make the world a better place.  Thanks so much for your taking the time to help a newbie out!

Comment: This works for me, but I'm not sure I understand the `for` statement here.  Can you elaborate on how that results in a list for `ofs`?

Answer (score 4):

A very partial answer: As mentioned in the [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#Variables),

> variables are bound to expressions and keep a single value during
> their entire lifetime

they are like constants. So you can't use a for loop they way you think.

I do not have the answer. You will probably have to find a smart, vector-based way to prepare the your [5,7,12,13] vector. Maybe if you decribe how you construct your initial vector, I could assist with ideas. Or you can just wait for an answer from a more experienced user :)

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I guess reading documentation has its benefits!  This is a weird concept for me.  The answer above provided what I needed.